# How to add a suffix onto column names based on existing column name?

Tags: r

At the moment, the code below is not very reproducible as I am adding the suffix based on column numbers. How would I modify this code to add the suffix to all columns beginning with "rs" instead of using column numbers?

```
# make data 

df <- data.frame(y1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), y2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), y3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), y4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.22),
                       rs1 = rnorm(100), rs2 = rnorm(100), rs3 = rnorm(100),
                       rs4 = rnorm(100), rs5 = rnorm(100), rs6 = rnorm(100))


# add suffix to column names beginning with rs
colnames(df)[5:10] <- paste(colnames(df)[5:10], "C", sep = "_")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` or `startsWith` from `base R`

```
nm1 <- startsWith(names(df), "rs")
# // or with grep
nm1 <- grep("^rs", names(df))
names(df)[nm1] <- paste0(names(df)[nm1], "_C")
```

---

Or using `rename_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('rs')), ~ str_c(., '_C'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using basic R code:

```
start_with_rs<-substr(colnames(df),1,2)=="rs" #Boolean vector with T/F based on starting "rs"

#Rename
colnames(df)[start_with_rs]<- paste(colnames(df)[start_with_rs], "C", sep = "_")
        colnames(df)
         [1] "y1"    "y2"    "y3"    "y4"    "rs1_C" "rs2_C" "rs3_C" "rs4_C" "rs5_C" "rs6_C"
```